Failed to process selector key | TCP Communication SPI Connection timed out
Ignite: 2.15
In our ignite cluster, we have one ignite server and node1 to node5 present. All nodes are unique and different functioning than other. Ignite server, node1 to node4 are running on windows machine and node5 is running on Linux machine.
All works fine and suddenly for around 15-20 minutes the communication created from node5 to node1 doesn't respond and we receive below exception in the logs.
For same source node1 ip-port 10.83.141.35:53590 to destination node5 ip-port 121.128.133.124:48104 we see below log entries
01:22:42:367068|2019-00218:Tracer_Ignite [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {INFO} Action {TCP client created [client=GridTcpNioCommunicationClient -----Truncated-----  Thread {AuthenticationThread}
01:22:42:367173|2089-00218:Tracer_Ignite [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {The node client is going to create a connection [nodeId=9dea71b4-8375-4957-a1bc-a37eeed909c6 -----Truncated-----  Thread {AuthenticationThread}
02:26:40:098231|1951-00120:Tracer_Ignite [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {Will move session to less loaded writer [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl -----Truncated----- {nio-acceptor-tcp-comm-#27%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
02:26:40:098305|2049-00120:Tracer_Ignite [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {Offered move [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl -----Truncated----- Thread {nio-acceptor-tcp-comm-#27%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
02:26:40:098464|2281-00119:Tracer_Ignite [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {Started moving [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl -----Truncated-----  grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#26%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
02:26:40:098677|1919-00117:Tracer_Ignite [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {DEBUG} Action {Finishing moving [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl -----Truncated-----  Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#24%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
Tracer_Ignite [class org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi]: {ERROR} Action {Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl -----Truncated-----  Thread {grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-1-#24%TcpCommunicationSpi%}
java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:330)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:284)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:259)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:417)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1351)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2526)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2281)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

We do not see any system critical thread log.
Here is the ignite configuration:
Communication SPI config

  <property name="localPortRange" value="20" />
  <!-- Explicitly configure TCP communication SPI changing local port number for the nodes from this cluster. -->
   <bean id="communicationSpiBean" class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">

    <property name="localPort" value="48100" />
    <property name="slowClientQueueLimit" value="100000" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTimeout" value="30000" />
    <property name="usePairedConnections" value="true" />
  </bean>

---------other config-----------

    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
   
    <property name="gridName" value="AppCluster"/>

    <property name="metricsLogFrequency" value="0"/>

    <property name="metricsUpdateFrequency" value="2000"/><!-- default: 2000 -->

    <property name="failureDetectionTimeout" value="10000"/><!-- default: 10000 --><!-- Should be greater then 'metricsUpdateFrequency' to prevent unnecessary status checking -->

    <property name="clientFailureDetectionTimeout" value="30000"/><!-- default: 30000 --> 

    <!-- Must be greater or equal to 'metricsUpdateFrequency' -->
    <property name="systemWorkerBlockedTimeout" value="300000"/>

    <property name="failureHandler">
       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.failure.StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler">
        <constructor-arg name="timeout" value="300000"/>
        <constructor-arg name="tryStop" value="true"/>
       </bean>
    </property>

Could someone point out the problem here?

I am sorry, but I need some clarity in order to provide any assistance! You mention that you have 1 server and furthermore you appear to have 5 nodes running on that 1 server (physical host) correct? If the above is true, then I would first ask why 5 nodes on 1 host? You are not really getting any benefits of having N nodes on 1 host! Also why different OS'es? I assume these are all VM's, correct? This deployment if the above is true only adds additional virtualization overhead to a system that is designed to be a distributed data processing cluster. If your host fails then all is dead!

5 nodes solves different purpose. There is no failover currently present.
all nodes are think clients and registers on the server topology. Both Linux and windows are VMs. Node5 connects to other non ignite components running on Linux. So node5 added on Linux, no specific reason.
